# VScode extension # to id

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-code, shortcut

I have seen many people writing "#someword" as a shortcut for

```
<div id="someword"></div>
```

and also ".someword" as a shortcut for

```
<div class="someword"></div>
```

Do you know how to do that?
Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The functionality is build in. You do not need any additional extension. As soon as you save your file as a `*.html` you can use the `#someword` syntax and the `Emmet Abbreviation` pops up automatically-

Answer (score 1):

It should be Emmet, it is installed by default in vscode.

Take a look here https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/emmet

Answer (score 0):

Tagname.atrributevalue+tab will create an html tag with attribute(always attribute will be class) and attribute value

Tagname#atrributevalue+tab will create an html tag with attribute(always attribute will be id) and attribute value

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).